# how to fix "IntegrityError at /prog UNIQUE constraint failed: grading_program_of_study.student_id" in django

Tags: django

i am setting up a django applcation in which am using one to one field when i add student detial from the backend it works well but form a frontend form it gives the following error "IntegrityError at /prog
UNIQUE constraint failed: grading_program_of_study.student_id
"

```
//////////////my view code////////////////

def prog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['program_name'] and request.POST['date_of_entry'] and request.POST['faculty']and request.POST['department'] and request.POST['program_type'] and request.POST['date_of_complition']:
            Program_of_study = program_of_study()
            Program_of_study.program_name = request.POST['program_name']
            Program_of_study.date_of_entry = request.POST['date_of_entry']
            Program_of_study.faculty = request.POST['faculty']
            Program_of_study.department = request.POST['department']
            Program_of_study.department = request.POST['program_type']
            Program_of_study.date_of_complition = request.POST['date_of_complition']

            Program_of_study.save()


            return redirect('home',{'sucess':'Program added sucessfully'})

        else:
            return render(request,'grading/home.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'grading/home.html')



########### my model code################################

class program_of_study(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(student_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = 1)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_entry = models.DateField()
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_complition = models.DateField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_name
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not specifying an instance for `program_of_study.student`. How are you determining which student the program of study should be created for?

Comment: the most recent student but i actually wanted to add student id field but its rejected it

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the default value in the student field. Since you have a OneToOne relation, you can't repeat values, so you can't have a default.

```
student = models.OneToOneField(student_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 1)
```

What you can do to solve the issue is change the field type to ForeignKey, or remove the default value.

Comment: i have removed the default but it still not woking

Comment: In your view you are setting student when creating your Program_of_study. You also have to do that

Answer (score 0):

thank God i have fixed the problem with just a single line of code the error was that i was trying to save the data as a string instead of as an integer

############### the solution to the problem

Program_of_study.student = student_details.object.latest(id)